# Regular Expression for Multiple values separated by specific keywords

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on application which needs user to add multiple GroupName in textbox.
 1. The GroupName can be separated by "," / "or" / "OR".
 2. Input should not start with or end with "," / "or" / "OR".

eg: GroupName, GroupName or GroupName OR GroupName or GroupName, GroupName, GroupName, GroupName or GroupName

For this i have written a Regular expression but iam not able to implement the 2nd point.
The regex developed so far is
/^([a-zA-Z])(\s|[,\s]|[or\s]|[OR\s]?[a-zA-Z])*$/

It would be good help if someone from community would participate to help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to validate the input string or what is the regex for? groupnames can't contain "_", "-", spaces, numbers or other characters except letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to validate the input:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s*(?:or|OR|,)\s*[a-zA-Z]+)*$/
```

*([explanation here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2b%28?%3a%5Cs%2a%28?%3aor%7COR%7C,%29%5Cs%2a%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2b%29%2a%24))